# Adding data to Paginated Results

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, eloquent, lumen

Adding data after storing a query in a variable by using `->find($id)` is pretty straight forward. I can use..

```
 $photo = Photo::with('likes')->find($id);
 $photo->total_likes = $photo->likes->count();

 return response()->json($photos, 200);
```

works like charm.. So I don't need to use a for loop

---

However, what if I want to add data to paginated results?

```
$photos = Photo::with('likes')->where('user_id', $user_id)->paginate(15);

return response()->json($photos, 200);
```

With that, the data I receive in return:

```
"total": 5,
"per_page": 15,
"current_page": 1,
"last_page": 1,
"next_page_url": null,
"prev_page_url": null,
"from": 1,
"to": 5,
"data": [
    "likes": [each like object..]
       ]
```

How can I use `$photo->total_likes = $photo->likes->count();` approach to return total count after paginated result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating a custom paginator instance. For example:

```
public function getNews() {
    $news = \App\News::select()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();

    $collection = $this->prepareNews($news);

    return $this->paginator($collection);
}

protected function prepareNews($news) {
    // do stuff with your news/whatever here
    foreach($news as $item) {
         'title' => $item->title,
         'category' => $item->category_id != 0 ? $categories[$item->category_id]['name'] : null,
    }
    // Note the collect, this is important 
    return collect($arr);
}

protected function paginator(\Illuminate\Support\Collection $items, $perPage = 3) {
    //Get current page form url e.g. &page=6
    $currentPage = Paginator::resolveCurrentPage() - 1;
    $currentPageSearchResults = $items->slice($currentPage * $perPage, $perPage)->all();


    return new Paginator($currentPageSearchResults, count($items), $perPage);
}
```

Comment: So there isn't any easy ways like the other? :/ That's bad. Thanks anyway!

Comment: That is the easiest method I know and if you look at the code, it is pretty easy anyway